# Не получается отсортировать многомерный массив по нескольким полям

Tags: php

Есть следующий массив:

```
array(
  0 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 3, 'is_image' => 0),
  1 => array('total' => 1, 'ttl' => 4, 'is_image' => 1),
  2 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 3, 'is_image' => 1),
  3 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 2, 'is_image' => 1),
  4 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 1, 'is_image' => 0),
)
```

Нужно его осортировать сначала по полю total, затем по полю ttl, а потом по полю is_image, т.е. в результате нужно получить такой массив:

```
array(
  0 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 3, 'is_image' => 1),
  1 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 3, 'is_image' => 0),
  2 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 2, 'is_image' => 1),
  3 => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 1, 'is_image' => 0),
  4 => array('total' => 1, 'ttl' => 4, 'is_image' => 1),
)
```

Пробую отсортировать его с помощью array_multisort, но что-то идёт не так и правильная сортировка не получается:

```
$total = [];
$ttr = [];
$is_image = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $total[$key]=$value['total'];
    $ttr[$key]=$value['ttr'];
    $is_image[$key]=$value['is_image'];
}

array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $ttr, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $is_image, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $array);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php и http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php сортируйте как угодно с помощью своей функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    0    => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 3, 'is_image' => 0),
    1    => array('total' => 1, 'ttl' => 4, 'is_image' => 1),
    2    => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 3, 'is_image' => 1),
    3    => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 2, 'is_image' => 1),
    4    => array('total' => 2, 'ttl' => 1, 'is_image' => 0),
);

$keys = ['total', 'ttl', 'is_image'];


usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $k)
    {
        if ($a[$k] != $b[$k]) {
            return ($a[$k] < $b[$k]) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Кажется работает, теперь буду разбираться как это работает, и применять еще и к другому случаю.